# HttpPostedFileBase does not work for Iphone

Tags: asp.net, iphone, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been working on a web application using mvc 5 asp.net in visual studio community 2017. My only goal was to be able to upload an image to a database for any device, since trying to test devices(especially IOS) in debugger is fruitless, I deployed the web app to an IIS, and started testing. All kinds of devices worked pc, samsung even ipad, but when i tried to upload an image using iphone with the chrome app there are problems, and as far as I know i can't see any exception that happens in the IIS I started to cut my code down to the essentials trying to figure out what is going wrong, and in the end my code looked like this

-- view file --

```
<div class="form-group">
            Image/Document to upload
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="uploader" id="image"
                       accept="image/*"
                        />
            </div>
</div>
```

-- controller --

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase uploader)
{
    db.Image imagetoupload;
    if (uploader != null && uploader.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        imagetoupload.SizeOfFile = uploader.ContentLength;
        using (var reader = new 
        System.IO.BinaryReader(uploader.InputStream))
                    {
                        imagetoupload.ImageContent = reader.ReadBytes(uploader.ContentLength);
                    }
     }
     else{
          imagetoupload.ImageContent = new byte[0];
          imagetoupload.SizeOfFile = 0;
     }
     db.image.Add(imagetoupload);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the iphone does not send an image, it goes through fine, but if I try to upload an image it doesn't, i have been ripping out my hair over this since I can't figure out what is wrong, and the only logical conclusion i can come to is that httpPostedFileBase doesn't work with iphone.